Tracking Background Location with React Native
Hi I just started learning react native and expo. Right now I'm trying to build an app that collects users' location even when the app is in the background(with their consent). I've been using expo-location, but it turns out that user needs to select 'always' when they're asked for location tracking permission but expo-go doesn't support that. What are some ways I can test my app?
I've been looking at using EAS service to build a standalone app to test or using a custom development client but I'm not sure if they achieve what I want. Any suggestions?

To test background location tracking in your React Native app using Expo, you indeed have a couple of viable options:

EAS Build: Building a standalone app using Expo Application Services (EAS) allows you to test features like background location tracking, which require the "always" location permission. This approach will enable you to create an APK for Android or an IPA for iOS, which can be installed and tested on actual devices. Here's a basic overview of the steps:

Install EAS CLI (npm install -g eas-cli).
Configure your project with eas.json.
Run eas build to create a standalone build.
Install the build on your device for testing.


Custom Development Client: This approach is beneficial for rapid development and testing without the need for a full build each time. It allows you to use a custom client with your desired native code changes and permissions. To set this up:

Use EAS Build to create a custom client.
Configure your app to request the "always" location permission.
Install the custom client on your device and use it to run your project.



Here are some additional tips:

Permissions Handling: Ensure that your app.json or app.config.js includes the required permissions. For example:
{
  "expo": {
    "ios": {
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription": "We need your location to provide better services.",
        "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription": "We need your location to provide better services."
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "permissions": [
        "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
        "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
        "ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"
      ]
    }
  }
}


Testing in Different Scenarios: Test the app in various scenarios, such as when the app is in the foreground, background, and completely closed, to ensure the background location tracking works as expected.

Both methods (EAS Build and Custom Development Client) are suitable for testing your app's background location tracking. Using EAS Build might be a bit slower due to the build process, but it ensures you are testing the actual standalone app behavior. The Custom Development Client is faster for iterative testing during development.

It looks like it's gpted bro. I got almost the same answer when I asked gpt this moring:)
